# Arduino Nano clone doesn't upload Linux

Tags: uploading, clones, ch340, upload

I've been trying to upload sketch to Arduino Nano clone (CH340G RS232 to USB converter). I have ArchLinux. My port is detected as /dev/ttyUSB0 (Official Arduino Uno is /dev/ttyACM0). After trying to upload a sketch avrdude responds with

```
avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x44
```

or

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): can't communicate with device: resp=0x88
```

After using verbose output it seems like it does not read from the arduino back to PC. I have all my permissions correct and everything was working to this date. I also used many arduinos which I also burned bootloader on using my Arduino Uno. Everything also works on seconds PC with Windows. Any ideas?

Linux log:

```
/usr/share/arduino/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /usr/share/arduino/hardware -hardware /home/jakub/.arduino15/packages -tools /usr/share/arduino/tools-builder -tools /home/jakub/.arduino15/packages -libraries /home/jakub/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328 -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10809 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_539099 -warnings=all -build-cache /tmp/arduino_cache_182117 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -verbose /usr/share/arduino/examples/01.Basics/Blink/Blink.ino
/usr/share/arduino/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /usr/share/arduino/hardware -hardware /home/jakub/.arduino15/packages -tools /usr/share/arduino/tools-builder -tools /home/jakub/.arduino15/packages -libraries /home/jakub/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328 -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10809 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_539099 -warnings=all -build-cache /tmp/arduino_cache_182117 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -verbose /usr/share/arduino/examples/01.Basics/Blink/Blink.ino
Using board 'nano' from platform in folder: /home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.2
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.2
Detecting libraries used...
/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.2/cores/arduino -I/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.2/variants/eightanaloginputs /tmp/arduino_build_539099/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp -o /dev/null
Generating function prototypes...
/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.2/cores/arduino -I/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.2/variants/eightanaloginputs /tmp/arduino_build_539099/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp -o /tmp/arduino_build_539099/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
/usr/bin/arduino-ctags -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives /tmp/arduino_build_539099/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
Kompilujem projekt...
/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.2/cores/arduino -I/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.2/variants/eightanaloginputs /tmp/arduino_build_539099/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp -o /tmp/arduino_build_539099/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp.o
Compiling libraries...
Compiling core...
Using precompiled core: /tmp/arduino_cache_182117/core/core_arduino_avr_nano_cpu_atmega328_6ffe6e1951fbeab8145453327f70df2d.a
Linking everything together...
/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/avr-gcc -Wall -Wextra -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o /tmp/arduino_build_539099/Blink.ino.elf /tmp/arduino_build_539099/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp.o /tmp/arduino_build_539099/../arduino_cache_182117/core/core_arduino_avr_nano_cpu_atmega328_6ffe6e1951fbeab8145453327f70df2d.a -L/tmp/arduino_build_539099 -lm
/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 /tmp/arduino_build_539099/Blink.ino.elf /tmp/arduino_build_539099/Blink.ino.eep
/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom /tmp/arduino_build_539099/Blink.ino.elf /tmp/arduino_build_539099/Blink.ino.hex
/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/avr-size -A /tmp/arduino_build_539099/Blink.ino.elf
Projekt zaberá 924 bytov (3%) pamäte pre program. Maximum je 30720 bytov.
Globálne premenné zaberajú 9 bytov (0%)  dynamickej pamäti, 2039 bytov zostáva pre lokálne premenné. Maximum je 2048 bytov.
/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude -C/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/ttyUSB0 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/arduino_build_539099/Blink.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "/home/jakub/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"
     User configuration file is "/home/jakub/.avrduderc"
     User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

     Using Port                    : /dev/ttyUSB0
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
     AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
     Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
     PAGEL                         : PD7
     BS2                           : PC2
     RESET disposition             : dedicated
     RETRY pulse                   : SCK
     serial program mode           : yes
     parallel program mode         : yes
     Timeout                       : 200
     StabDelay                     : 100
     CmdexeDelay                   : 25
     SyncLoops                     : 32
     ByteDelay                     : 0
     PollIndex                     : 3
     PollValue                     : 0x53
     Memory Detail                 :

                              Block Poll               Page                       Polled
       Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
       ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
       eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
       flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
       lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
       signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

     Programmer Type : Arduino
     Description     : Arduino

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0xfc

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0xfc

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0xfc
         Hardware Version: 4238814
         Firmware Version: 21984432.4
         Topcard         : Unknown

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0xfc

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0xfc

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0xfc

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0xfc
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 1992555.2 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us


avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x88

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0xfc
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | 
avrdude: arduino_read_sig_bytes(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x10, resp=0xfc
avrdude: error reading signature data for part "ATmega328P", rc=-3
avrdude: error reading signature data, rc=-3

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Windows log:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Adamko\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328 -ide-version=10807 -build-path C:\Users\Adamko\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_858804 -warnings=all -build-cache C:\Users\Adamko\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_611368 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\examples\01.Basics\Blink\Blink.ino
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Adamko\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328 -ide-version=10807 -build-path C:\Users\Adamko\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_858804 -warnings=all -build-cache C:\Users\Adamko\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_611368 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\examples\01.Basics\Blink\Blink.ino
Using board 'nano' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Detecting libraries used...
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o nul
Generating function prototypes...
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\tools-builder\\ctags\\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Kompilujem projekt...
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp.o"
Compiling libraries...
Compiling core...
Using precompiled core: C:\Users\Adamko\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_611368\core\core_arduino_avr_nano_cpu_atmega328_0c812875ac70eb4a9b385d8fb077f54c.a
Linking everything together...
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -Wall -Wextra -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804/..\\arduino_cache_611368\\core\\core_arduino_avr_nano_cpu_atmega328_0c812875ac70eb4a9b385d8fb077f54c.a" "-LC:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804" -lm
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804/Blink.ino.eep"
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804/Blink.ino.hex"
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\tools\\avr/bin/avr-size" -A "C:\\Users\\Adamko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_858804/Blink.ino.elf"
Projekt zaberá 930 bytov (3%) pamäte pre program. Maximum je 30720 bytov.
Globálne premenné zaberajú 9 bytov (0%)  dynamickej pamäti, 2039 bytov zostáva pre lokálne premenné. Maximum je 2048 bytov.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM3 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\Adamko\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_858804/Blink.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM3
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : Arduino
         Description     : Arduino
         Hardware Version: 3
         Firmware Version: 4.4
         Vtarget         : 0.3 V
         Varef           : 0.3 V
         Oscillator      : 28.800 kHz
         SCK period      : 3.3 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: reading input file "C:\Users\Adamko\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_858804/Blink.ino.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (930 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.16s

avrdude: 930 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against C:\Users\Adamko\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_858804/Blink.ino.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file C:\Users\Adamko\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_858804/Blink.ino.hex:
avrdude: input file C:\Users\Adamko\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_858804/Blink.ino.hex contains 930 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.12s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 930 bytes of flash verified

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

**UPDATE** Added the avrdude logs and command line.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104344/discussion-on-question-by-jakub-janek-arduino-nano-clone-doesnt-upload-linux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in kernel ch341 driver. Using 5.3.3 on Archlinux and 5.6 rc1.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e33eab9ded328ccc14308afa51b5be7cbe78d30b/drivers/usb/serial/ch341.c

This driver version compiled using this Makefile

```
obj-m += ch341-m.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

reload: all
        sudo rmmod ch341-m ||true
        sudo insmod ./ch341-m.ko
```

Made it upload again. Hope it will be solved in kernel soon. I think the problem is addressed here

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/35714565089e5e8b091c1155517b67e29118f09d#commitcomment-37154772

But the guy said it was solved in 5.6 rc1 which was not in my case.

Comment: I get `make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/jrs/Builds/ch341-driver/ch341-m.o', needed by '__build'.  Stop.` How does that Makefile work, what prerequisites do you have to have in place?

Comment: Makefile is a build configuration file. If you download the link I provided (the first one) and save it with a name "ch341-m" which is said in the mamefile, to the same directory you can use "make" and "make reload" you should have ch341 driver installed. For more questions move to chat in the question comment. Thank you.

Comment: Got it working now by downloading the whole kernel source, copying the file you linked to into `drivers/usb/serial` and following https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compile_kernel_module. Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try disconnecting any VCC port you have and see if it uploads if it does, after uploading the code reconnect the VCC ports again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104465/discussion-on-answer-by-scotchex-arduino-nano-clone-doesnt-upload-linux).