# Arduino NANO (CH340) error while flashing bootloader

Tags: arduino-nano, bootloader, avrdude, ch340

Ok. So I'm close to tearing me hair out on this one.

I have a batch of cheap Arduino Nano clones, that just straight up won't work. (I HAVE gotten one of them to work, but I suspect that was by pure coincidence)

Anyway, I feel like I've tried everything to make them work.
I am consistently getting

> Device signature = 0xffffff

errors from avrdude, which I believe is a hardware problem. Up til now I have tried:

- Installed CH340 drivers, no difference
- Tried to burn bootloader using Uno as an ISP (with 10uF cap between reset and ground!)
- Tried the "(Old Bootloader)" option in the IDE

All I have left is to desolder the entire board and troubleshoot each single component, but... no, I want to keep my sanity intact, thaaank you!

Any ideas on how I should move forward here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arduino Nano clone doesn't upload Linux](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/72463/arduino-nano-clone-doesnt-upload-linux)

Comment: was the bootloader burning successful?

Comment: Had the same problem on Windows 10, using the CH340 drivers from their website:
http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_EXE.html

Comment: @Juraj no, unfortunately :(

Comment: @VE7JRO I am running Ubutnu 16.04, with the 4.15.0-76-generic kernal

Comment: Realize that my Ubuntu install is **severely** outdated. The problem is that it wont even flash the bootloader on Windows 10, which is up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

Hit reset randomly in the first few seconds of uploading/burning.

Comment: Tried, no change. Thank you though!